# Sharing modules between multiple Puppet environments

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I am having an absolute nightmare getting Puppet to load a group of modules that will be shared between multiple environments.

The modules in puppet/environments/development/modules get loaded fine BUT none of the dependencies in puppet/modules can be found.

The folder structure for my project is:

[image]

And the project is up on bitbucket:
https://bitbucket.org/andrew_hancox/vagrantmoodle

Answer (score 1):

What I do usually to manage the modules dependencies is to have a shell script that will install the modules directly, this way it downloads the necessary dependency as well as pushing to the right place.

I will have in my Vagrantfile

```
  node_config.vm.provision "shell", path: "puppet/script/install-puppet-modules-app.sh"
  node_config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.environment = "production"
    puppet.environment_path = "puppet/environments"
    puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/environments/production/manifests"
    puppet.manifest_file = "base-app.pp"
    #puppet.options = "--verbose --trace"
  end
```

The script shell is something like

```
#!/bin/bash

puppet module install puppet-nginx --version 0.4.0
```

here you will have your apache, mysql module etc

the `environment.conf` file will locate the default place for the installed module

```
# environment configuration used by Puppet4
modulepath          = /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules:$basemodulepath
```

Comment: just pushed a quick example on github https://github.com/fhenri/nginx-loadbalancer/tree/puppetv4

Comment: Are the Puppet class methods in Vagrant working again? They were broken for a while.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Hi Matt, in which version ? I was using class mainly in puppet 3.x and did the quick testing as I wanted to test vagrant provisioning with puppet 4 and seems to work fine

Comment: It was Vagrant updates that broke it and not Puppet as I recall. Hashicorp does not do qa/build/release so this kind of stuff happens.

Answer (score 0):

I got the whole thing working properly thanks to @michael-mulqueen

The way he fixed it was by setting the module path in the vagrant file:

`puppet.module_path = ["puppet/modules", "puppet/environments/development/modules"]`

You can see this in the repo referenced in the question.